# Keep transition state when input field contains text - CSS3

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

**[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Lh0pp0kn/1/)**

I have the following input field which I have applied some CSS transitions on:

```
<input type="text" id="input-text" class="both input-text">

<label id="test" for="input-text" class="label-text-first"></label>
<label id="test" for="input-text" class="label-text-second"></label>
<label id="test" for="input-text" class="both label-text-placeholder"></label>
```

My problem is, I want to keep the transitioned state if the input-field contains text, otherwise it's allowed to go back to the original position.

Is this possible to achieve through pure CSS3 or do I need javascript?

Comment: according to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16952526/detect-if-an-input-has-text-in-it-using-css CSS cannot detect the value of an input. I think you'll need javascript. You could add a class to your input when it has a value (with JS), then apply the `:not(.your-class-here)` selector to your input transition. Then it wouldn't get applied when the input has a value. Just a thought.

Comment: @lhan hm - interesting approach. I'll give that a go, thanks.

Comment: I would go with @jaunts approach, with pure css. very slick!

Comment: see my solution on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32519117/why-is-inputinvalid-true-when-the-input-is-empty/32519875#32519875

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually using the [required attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-required), alongside with the [:valid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Avalid) pseudo selector, we can do this with pure CSS, as demonstrated:

```css
html {
  background-color: #43394a;
  color: #555;
  font-family: 'Lato', 'Arial', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  overflow: hidden;
}
label,
input {
  position: absolute;
  width: 15%;
  height: 15%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  border: 2px solid white;
}
.label-text-first {
  transform: translate(-100%, -50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-100%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-100%, -50%);
  border: 0.4vw solid #9686a2;
  border-right: none;
  transition: left 0.4s;
  -webkit-transition: left 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: left 0.4s;
}
.label-text-second {
  transform: translate(-0%, -50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-0%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-0%, -50%);
  border: 0.4vw solid #9686a2;
  border-left: none;
  transition: left 0.4s;
  -webkit-transition: left 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: left 0.4s;
}
.both {
  width: 28%;
  height: 12%;
  text-align: center;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: transparent;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  font-size: 2.0vw;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #9686a2;
}
.label-text-placeholder {
  z-index: 8888;
  transition: transform 0.4s;
  -webkit-transition-property: transform;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: transform 0.4s;
}
.label-text-placeholder:before {
  display: block;
  content: 'First Name';
  line-height: 12.0vh;
}
.input-text:focus ~ .label-text-first,.input-text:valid ~ .label-text-first {
  left: 49%;
  transition: left 0.4s;
  -webkit-transition: left 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: left 0.4s;
}
.input-text:focus ~ .label-text-second,.input-text:valid  ~ .label-text-second{
  left: 51%;
  transition: left 0.4s;
  -webkit-transition: left 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: left 0.4s;
}
.input-text:focus ~ .label-text-placeholder,.input-text:valid  ~ .label-text-placeholder {
  transform: translate(-50%, 65%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 65%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, 65%);
  transition: transform 0.4s;
  -webkit-transition: transform 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: transform 0.4s;
}
```

```html
<form>
<input type="text" id="input-text" class="both input-text" required>

<label id="test" for="input-text" class="label-text-first"></label>
<label id="test" for="input-text" class="label-text-second"></label>
<label id="test" for="input-text" class="both label-text-placeholder"></label>
</form>
```

Comment: wow - this is very cool. I was not aware of these selectors. +1

Comment: holy f - this is awesome! Thanks!

Comment: What is the specific declaration that is causing the transition to remain bound when the input control has content?

Comment: @Donato By adding the 'required' attribute to an input you can test to see whether the user has inputted anything using the ':valid' pseudo-selector; after all something required must have a value otherwise it's invalid.

Answer (score 1):

Try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lh0pp0kn/2/)

It is done with pure css.

You gonna need to add required attribute to your input like this:

```
<input type="text" id="input-text" class="both input-text" required>
```

and to your css add this rules:

```
.input-text:focus ~ .label-text-first, .input-text:valid ~ .label-text-placeholder {
    left: 49%;
    transition: left 0.4s;
    -webkit-transition: left 0.4s;
    -moz-transition: left 0.4s;
}

.input-text:focus ~ .label-text-second, .input-text:valid ~ .label-text-placeholder{
    left: 51%;
    transition: left 0.4s;
    -webkit-transition: left 0.4s;
    -moz-transition: left 0.4s;
}

.input-text:focus ~ .label-text-placeholder, .input-text:valid ~ .label-text-placeholder {
    transform: translate(-50%, 65%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 65%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, 65%);
    transition: transform 0.4s;
    -webkit-transition: transform 0.4s;
    -moz-transition: transform 0.4s;
}
```

**Notice**

I just added this rule `.input-text:valid ~ .label-text-placeholder` to yours.

This rule will place the placeholder inside input text as long as it is not valid, i.e. empty. Otherwise it will be under the input.